# Обработчик двойного нажатия(через onTouch())

Tags: java, android

В onTouch() нужно задать действие при одном нажатии(что сделать легко) и при двух быстрых нажатиях(желательно, чтобы можно было задать максимальный интервал времени между касаниями). Единственное что лезет в голову, это вначале действия в случае одного нажатия поставить sleep на время, и если было второе касание выполнить соответствующий код. Sleep() работает (удивительно), но по ощущениям он работает так, как будто при касании экрана не срабатывает новый поток обработчика, а есть один поток обработчик который линейно обрабатывает нажатия. Как сделать, чтобы обработчик ждал некоторое время следующее касание?

Comment: А почему не сделать короткое нажатие и длинное нажатие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, в обработчике нажатия стоит прибавление количества нажатий и если не был вызван, то вызывается поток который засыпает на секунду. Спросони поток определяет какое сообщение послать хендлеру, на основе того, сколько за это время произошло нажатий. Хендлеру основываясь на сообщении выполняет нужный код

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте такой вариант

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("onDoubleTap", "Open new activty here");
        return true;
    }
});
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```